# How to render a page based on the data obtained on the basis of a request, which is made on the basis of another request. (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, render

I have this endpoint to get basic data for my app:
https://app.subsocial.network/subid/api/v1/chains/properties

In the response i have an object like this:

```
{
  "edgeware": {
    "ss58Format": 7,
    "tokenDecimals": [
      18
    ],
    "tokenSymbol": [
      "EDG"
    ],
    "icon": "edgeware-circle.svg",
    "name": "Edgeware"
  },
  "chainx": {
    "icon": "chainx.svg",
    "name": "ChainX"
  },
```

What I need is to display name and icon for each particular object (for example in this case for the first instance it will be like this by mapping the main object:
the name we can get like that: {item.name}
and the icons we can get like this: <img src={`https://app.subsocial.network/subid/icons/${item.icon}`}/>
).

BUT! Near each particular item I also need a status of a request, that was made to a particular url, based on each object. For example for the first object it will be https://app.subsocial.network/subid/api/v1/check/edgeware. This request is returning a boolean value and i just want to display it near the name and icon.
For now I have this code, and i cant figure out how to make second request and to display it. Besides, I need to update all the statuses every 5 minutes. I trying this, but **I have all true or all false values, despite that API is work correct.**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ImageContainer, IconImage, ItemWrapper, RedSquare, GreenSquare, ItemName, LoadingWrapper } from './styled-containers';


function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [finalData, setFinalData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const transformData = (obj, statuses) => {
    const array = [];
    for (let key in obj) {
      array.push({ ...obj[key], statuses: statuses });
    }
    return array
  }

  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch('https://app.subsocial.network/subid/api/v1/chains/properties')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setData(data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    for (let key in data) {
      fetch(`https://app.subsocial.network/subid/api/v1/check/${key}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(itemStatus => setFinalData(transformData(data, itemStatus)))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
        .finally(setLoading(false))
    }
    setInterval(() => {
      fetchData()
    }, 30000)
  }, [data])

  console.log(finalData)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {loading ? <LoadingWrapper>...loading</LoadingWrapper> : finalData.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <ItemWrapper key={index}>
            <ImageContainer >
              <IconImage src={`https://app.subsocial.network/subid/icons/${item.icon}`} alt='' />
            </ImageContainer>
            <ItemName>{item.name}</ItemName>
            {finalData.statuses ? <GreenSquare /> : <RedSquare />}
          </ItemWrapper>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you need to add another `useEffect` with the dependency on the `data` state that was updated by the first fetch. Fetch from that second endpoint in that effect. And for timed update, add another state variable, use `setInterval`, to change that variable, and make this state a dependency of your first `useEffect`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have tried to do that, and It's almost done, but I have all the statuses with all true or all false values, despite that API is work correctly. Check out the changes to my question if you have couple minutes. Thank you!

Comment: The problem now is that `transformData` sets the status of the _last_ processed entry to _all_ objects. You need to use the `key` and only change the status of the object that matches that key. I've made a simple example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-http-6m1yu?file=/src/App.js)